# Fastest way to remove duplicates from std::list of a custom type

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

If this has been asked before please forgive me, I could not find it.
I have a custom type for which I can implement (fuzzy) equality but no `<` operator that is transitive.
The comparison is costly but I have not many elements.
I need to sort out polygons that are alomst identical (they overlap to a large fraction). Since ordering using `<` is impossible due to the lack of a transitive implementation I am using a std::list like the following:

```
typedef std::list<Polygon> PolyList;
PolyList purged(rawList);
for (PolyList::iterator iter= purged.begin(); iter!=  purged.end(); ++iter) {
  for(PolyList::iterator toRemove = find(boost::next(iter),purged.end(),*iter); toRemove != purged.end(); ){
      PolyList::iterator next = purged.erase(toRemove);
      toRemove = find(next,purged.end(),*iter);
    }
  }
```

The complexity is n*n/2 which is unavoidable in my opinion and 
while the algorithm works fine, it is still very cumbersome to read and write and I am almost sure there is a standard algorithm for it that I just don't know or at least something as fast but neater to type. As I said sorting is not an option due to the fuzzyness of the data so no unique set or sort.
Many thanks in advance for helping me out

Comment: Just add a comment saying what you are doing and why... *O(N^2) removal of duplicates, for each element find duplicates towards the end and remove them*

Comment: [std::list::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique).

Comment: What do you mean by "fuzzy"? Does your operator "<" satisfy conditions of strict weak ordering?

Comment: @Jesse, VJovic: `unique` will remove only *consecutive* duplicates, which can be achieved by first ordering, but it seems like Martin cannot really order the list before hand.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, probably a more thorough explanation is needed to answer the question.

Comment: @Krysztof: No it does not. With fuzzy I mean I want so sort out almost equal duplicates, in fact polygons that overlap to a certain fraction.

Comment: @David and Jesse: David is right: Unique does not work as you can also see in your reference (the tailing 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not going to find an asnwer in the Standard, since your "duplicates" sound like they're not transitive either. That's to say that `a==b && b==c` does not imply `a==c`.

For that reason alone, any algorithm has to compare all pairs, which gives you `(N*N-1)/2` comparisons (assuming your equality is symmetric, i.e. `a==b` *does* imply `b==a`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it pretty much summarizes my problem and sometimes one just needs someone to tell you: "Get over it" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a 'standard algorithm' for achieving what you want, but if you define a distance metric describing the difference between two polygons, then you can select (any) one polygon (call it the base polygon) and sort all the others on the distance from that polygon.  Only polygons whose distance from the base are similar may be similar to each other.

Now you only need to consider groups of polygons with similar distances, when deciding which to delete.  Without proving it - and I suspect the proof may be involved - I believe this is N log N.